# Updating total number on website with jQuery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, live

This below is displaying Total racers on my website but its not updating live. I need to referesh the page to grab the new number from the database, so what's the simple way of updating it live with jquery/javascript without refreshing the page? Thanks a lot for taking the time to check my question and possibly answer.

```
<div id="stats">
    <div id="racers">
        <span><?=number_format($racers, 0, ' ', ' ')?></span>
        RACERS
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I am not really good with jquery/javascript. Will it be possible to point me out how it should possibly look as code, so I won't screw something. Will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will suggest to use javascript setInterval function and within that call a function which will update the count in you DOM. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Ajax:

```
$.post('page.php', {
       postVariable : value
}, function(data) {
          //do something with data retrieved from php script
});
```

You set 'page.php' to a script that gets the data you want and echoes it.
You then retrieve what was echoed in the callback function(data);
So data will be the variable containing the value you need. You put this script in a
javascript function and call it when you need to make a request for information on the back-end.
If you have questions let me know. If you need more information on the ajax request you can find it here as well: api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I am building my website with codeigniter. So, I am really not sure how I can do this when this page isn't in my login member pages. It's non logged index page and it just grabs data from database and display it. Isn't there any other way of doing it based on the `$racers` value like updating the `<span>` with the new value?

Comment: Eww. Sorry it's why I hate using frameworks. I like to write all of my php from scratch, so I have complete freedom. It seems like there should still be a page you have to access to get the information isn't there? If you have a php page that displays this data, then all you need to do is make an ajax request to that page. Surely it allows you to make ajax requests to the back-end information though. Without knowing the structure though, it would be impossible to come up with a solution.

Comment: You can do this in Codeigniter. Make a new action in your controller that `echo`s out the current value. Use that action for the ajax request.

Comment: There are controllers for member pages but not for non logged ones such as the home/index one. I believe requesting also every second the page will overload more than normal, so basically there isn't a way of doing it like updating the specific `<span>` class for example and requesting the new information with the `$racers`` value? I should do all that in the home view page but not in any controller since it's only for logged in pages.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do this is the following:

**1. Have an action in a controller that outputs the total number of racers**

For example:

```
class Data extends CI_Controller {
    public function GetTotalRacers() {
        // This is dummy data. You need to replace this code with the correct 
        // number of racers retrieved from the database
        echo 14;
    }
}
```

Take note of where this action is. I'm assuming codeigniter will make the path something like `/Data/GetTotalRacers` in this case (that depends on how your route rules are configured).

**2. Use JavaScript to ask the server for the data and display the result on the page**

I recommend you have a method that runs every X number of seconds to refresh the total number of racers. To achieve this, you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval). Within the setInterval's function have an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to your action. Finally, display the value that's returned from the server:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        // Replace the url value with the correct url to access your action
        url: '/Data/GetTotalRacers',
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function( totalRacers ) {
        $("#racers span").text(totalRacers);
    });
}, 60000); // ex. Update every 60000ms
```

Note: I've never used codeigniter, but hopefully this description will help set you on the right path.

Comment: great but I would like to ask if this wont really overload the website or shouldn't mainly? Thanks!

Comment: @MobEn it'll be fine. It's such a small amount of data being sent. Just think about all the data being loading with a single page load and how that compares to this.